# How could I make it such that javascript in an external file works only on an image in a div inside a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm pretty new to web development, and am learning as I go along.

I have a PHP file (index.php) with code similar to that below (divs are defined in styles.css):

```
<div class='imgBox' id='imgBox'>
    <form name='graphForm' id='graphForm' method='post' action='/'>
        <input type='image' id='clicked' src='" . WebPath. "/images/graph.png' class='clickableImage' />
        <input name='x_y' id='x_y' type='hidden'/>
        <input name='p_id' id='p_id' type='hidden' value='".$RecordID."'/>          
    </form>
</div>
```

I've an external js file (showCoords.js) with the following code:

```
var tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip">' ).appendTo( 'body' )[0];

$( 'clickableImage' ).
    each(function () {
        var pos = $( this ).position(),
            top = pos.top,
            left = pos.left,
            width = $( this ).width(),
            height = $( this ).height();

        $( this ).
            mousemove(function ( e ) {
                var x = some_code_here,
                    y = some_code_here;

                $( tooltip ).text( x + ', ' + y ).css({
                    left: some_code_here,
                    top: some_code_here
                }).show();
            }).
            mouseleave(function () {
                //somestuff;
            }); 
    });
```

I currently have it such that I placed the showCoords.js file in the header file (header.html):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://blahblah.org/files/showCoords.js"></script>
```

My understanding is that I felt that this particular js should be loaded after the web page itself is loaded, and will then run automatically on the image in that div. Is this wrong?

Nothing is happening when I load the page, so I'd appreciate any help.

EDIT: In Firebug, I get a "ReferenceError: showCoords is not defined" error. Does this mean that showCoords.js is not even being included in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the document is ready before you fire all that code, we call it domready or documentready in javascript.

To do this in jQuery use this:

```
$(function() {
   // insert all your code here
});
```

You also are trying to select an element called clickable image. You probably want to find a class as @oxo has mentioned.

```
$('.clickableimage') would select <img class="clickabelimage" src="..." />
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So you're saying that everything in that js file should inside function() ? And where would this snippet  $('.clickableimage') would select <img class="clickabelimage" src="..." /> live?

Comment: Yes, none of your code should be run until the dom is ready.

$( 'clickableImage' ) isnt a selector, you need to specify the class or id

Comment: Ok, but in the PHP code you can see above, I did specify 'clickableImage' as the class, and 'clicked' as the id, and used that in the js code.

Comment: Yep, jquery uses css selectors so use .clickableimage rather than clickableimage  -  Note the period

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I notice that in Firebug, I get a "ReferenceError: showcoords is not defined" error. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: That means somewhere you are calling a variable/function/object called showcoords that you have never set/defined..

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. Try using `$( '.clickableImage' )` and start your debugging from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you are using the wrong way of selector.

`$( '<div id="tooltip">' )` should be `$('#tooltip')`

`$( 'clickableImage' )` should be `$('.clickableImage')`

Comment: Made the changes as you had suggested, but I see no difference.